# Test for assigning with a function

Tags: java, function

I was wondering if there is a test or some way of knowing if a function is called to assign or not, I mean telling the difference between...

```
int x = getX();
```

and just,

```
getX();
```

This doesn't have any practical use but I thought it would be good to know.

Is the possible?

Comment: You mean from inside the function?

Comment: Are you asking if you can check whether a function returns a value or returns nothing (returns void)?

Comment: I think he wants to check from inside the function if what it returns is used. AFAIK it's not possible.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Inside the body of a function!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but only through analyzing the compiled program's bytecode, making it extremely inconvenient.  Bytecode can be accessed at runtime by acquiring class bytes (either through [instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/) or other methods), and then analyzed with third party libraries such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/), or [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

To search for a local variable being assigned the result of a function, you'll want to look for the following bytecode pattern:

```
invokevirtual/static [class:method()signature]
xstore #stack
```

For the exact case of `int x = getX();`, the bytecode would be similar to:

```
invokevirtual [clazz:getX()I]
istore 1
```

But of course, the `clazz` is the actual class in which `getX()` is located, and the stack value of the stored local variable (`xstore`) would likely differ.  Furthermore, the `invokeXXX` call would be preceded by the loading of method arguments, including the implicit `this` instance.

All in all, this is possible, but not convenient, as understanding bytecode isn't a one-day experience.

Comment: Good answer, but without more work, searching for (and finding) the bytecode will only tell you that the result of *some* invocation of the function is assigned. Maybe I misunderstood, but I think the OP is asking about figuring it out for the current invocation.

Comment: @jerry As far as I can tell, the question doesn't mention the current invocation, nor determining what is done with the result of the current invocation from within the body of the invoked method itself.  Regardless, my answer points in the necessary direction to determine such information if necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's useful information, and you've already got a vote from me. I was basing my understanding on the statements `if a function is called to assign or not` and [`@OliCharlesworth Inside the body of a function!`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877286/test-for-assigning-with-a-function/16877414?noredirect=1#comment24347926_16877286). Since the OP accepted your answer, maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is just possible by analyzing the program's bytecode, as Vulcan just put straight.

Think of it in the way, the JRE does. Therefore you need to split the statement

```
int x = getX();
```

into two parts.

The first part the JRE will execute is `getX` and results in something like

```
int methodResult = getX();
```

The second part (which is a new statement for the JRE) is something like

```
int x = methodResult;
```

This is not the whole thing, the JRE does, but I think it helps to understand, why there is absolutely no direct connection between the variable `int x` and the body of the method `getX`.